# Combining deterministic finite automata

Tags: regular-language, automata, deterministic

I'm really new to this stuff so I apologize for the noobishness here.

construct a `Deterministic Finite Automaton` DFA recognizing the following language:

```
L= { w : w has at least two a's and an odd number of b's}.
```

The automate for each part of this `(at least 2 a's, odd # of b's)` are easy to make separately... Can anyone please explain a systematic way to combine them into one? Thanks.

Answer (score 28):

You can use following simple steps to construct combined DFA.

Let **Σ = {a<sub>1</sub> , a<sub>2</sub> , ...,a<sub>k</sub> }**. 
**1st step:** Design DFA for both languages and name their state Q<sub>0</sub>, Q<sub>1</sub>, ...

**2nd step :** Rename every state in both DFA uniquely i.e. rename all states in DFA as Q<sub>0</sub>, Q<sub>1</sub>, Q<sub>2</sub>, Q<sub>3</sub> , ... assuming you have started with subscript 0; that means none of the state would have same name.

**3rd Step:** Construct transition table(δ) by using following steps

**3a.** Start state of the combined DFA: 
      Take start state of both DFAs(DFA1 and DFA2) and name them as Q<sub>[ i , j ]</sub> where i and j are the subscript of start state of DFA1 and DFA2 respectively; i.e. Q<sub>i</sub> is start state of 1st DFA and Q<sub>j</sub> is start state of 2nd DFA and mark Q<sub>[i , j]</sub> as start state of combined DFA.

**3b.** Map state of both DFAs as 
           if δ(Q<sub>i</sub>,a<sub>k</sub>) = Q<sub>p1</sub> and δ(Q<sub>j</sub>,a<sub>k</sub>) = Q<sub>p2</sub> , where Q<sub>p1</sub> belongs to DFA1 and Q<sub>p2</sub> belongs to DFA2 then  δ(Q<sub>[ i , j ]</sub> , a<sub>k</sub>) = Q<sub>[p1,p2]</sub>

**3c**. fill entire table while there is any Q<sub>[i,j]</sub> remaining in transition table.

**3d**. Final state of the combined DFA:
      For `AND` case final state would be all Q<sub>[i , j]</sub> where Q<sub>i</sub> and Q<sub>j</sub>  are final state of DFA1 and DFA2 respectively.
      For `OR` case final state would be all Q<sub>[i , j]</sub> where either Q<sub>i</sub> or Q<sub>j</sub> is the final state of DFA1 and DFA2.

**4th step:**
Rename all Q<sub>[i, j]</sub> (uniquely) and draw DFA  this will be your result.

Example:

```
L= {w: w has at least two a's and an odd number of b's}.
```

**Step1:** 
DFA for odd number of b's .
[image]
DFA for at least 2 a's.
[image]

**Step2:** 
Rename the stae of DFA1 
[image]

**Step3(a,b,c):** 
Constructed transition table will be as.
[image: table]

**Step3d:** 
**Since we have to take AND of both DFA so final state would be Q<sub>[2,4]</sub>  , since it contains final state of both DFA .**
**If we have to take OR of both DFA the final state would be Q<sub>[0,4]</sub>,Q<sub>[2,3]</sub>,Q<sub>[1,4]</sub>,Q<sub>[2,4]</sub> .**
Transition table would like this after adding final state .

[image: final table]

**Step4:** 
Rename all states Q<sub>[i,j]</sub>
Q<sub>[0,3]</sub> to Q<sub>0</sub>
Q<sub>[1,3]</sub> to Q<sub>2</sub>
Q<sub>[0,4]</sub> to Q<sub>1</sub>
Q<sub>[2,3]</sub> to Q<sub>4</sub>
Q<sub>[1,4]</sub> to Q<sub>3</sub>
Q<sub>[2,4]</sub> to Q<sub>5</sub>
So final DFA would will look like as below .
[image: table]

Comment: would you also explain what's the science behind this? what's the regex?

Answer (score 0):

It's done using the [product](http://planetmath.org/productofautomata) of two automata.

Comment: I'm still stuck. Can anyone explain this with words?

Comment: I built the two automata that I can in jflap... how can I combine them into one?

Answer (score 0):

The Language `L` where `a` are at-least two and `b` are odd is an regular language. Its DFA is as below:
[image: a_and_odd_b]

In this DFA I have combined two `DFS`s conceptually!

```
DFA-1 = for odd number of `b`'s (placed vertically three times in diagram)
DFA-2 = for >=  two a           (placed Horizontally two times in diagram)
```

<sub>The DFA is too symptomatic and simple so I believe no need in word that how to combine both DFAs</sub>

To draw this DFA you are always keep track how many `b`s has been come either even or odd. `States 0, 2 and 4` means even number of `b` has been come. So you can divide this DFA in two parts vertically where bottom states at even `b`s and upper states at odd.

Also String is accepted if odd `b` hence final state should be in one of state in upper part.

not only number of `b`s is condition but `a` should be atleast `2`. So you can divide this DFA horizontally in three parts where number of `a`s are 0 at `state-0 and 1`, `a`s are one at `state-2 and 3` and `a`s are 2 at `state-4 and 5`. After first two `a`s any number of `a`s are allow in string so there is self loop on state `q4` and `q5`.

<sub>number of state required is six because, 2 state for odd even `b` and a s hould be atleast `2` so 3 states a=0, a=1, a=2, hence 2*3 = 6</sub>